# How do I move the Unity launcher to the left monitor?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop which I sometimes connect to a screen. The screen is positioned left to the laptop. The unity dock is kept on the laptop screen and does not move to the screen left side (which is the left of my working space). Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/742544) in Unity. Someone has [posted](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/742544/comments/4) a workaround, though I've not tried it myself.

Comment: It worked. I'll updated about any wired thing later.